# Show that the optimum value for the problem is $\frac{\lambda_1}{2}$

Tags: matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n$.

Let the problem be:

$$\text{minimize}\quad\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}$$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad \vec{x}^T\vec{x}=1$$

Show that the optimum value for the problem is $\frac{\lambda_1}{2}$

My try:

The Lagrangian is: $$L=\frac{1}{2} \vec{x}^T G\vec{x} + \mu(\vec{x}^T \vec{x}-1)$$

Then if we take the gradient with respect to $\vec{x}$ and set it equal to the zero vector:
$$\nabla_x L= G\vec{x}+2\mu\vec{x}=\vec{0}$$

Then $$\vec{x}=G^{-1}(-2\mu\vec{x})$$

I'm not sure on how to solve for $\vec{x}$ here. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $Gx + 2 \mu x = 0$ you have
$Gx = -2\mu x$, so $x$ must be a $(-2\mu)$-eigenvector of $G$, in which case $\frac{1}{2} x^\top G x = \frac{1}{2}(-2\mu) x^\top x = \frac{1}{2}(-2\mu).$

Here, $\mu$ must satisfy $(-2\mu) = \lambda_i$ for some $i$. Setting it so that $(-2\mu) = \lambda_1$ makes $\frac{1}{2} x^\top G x$ the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $Gx=-2\mu x$ implies that $x$ is an eigenvector of $G$.